# How to get an ever-changing class-name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

How to get an element that is constantly changing between:
`<li class="tab-li tab-error tab-active" bpm-tab="bpm-tab-event-mapping">`
and
`<li class="tab-li tab-active" bpm-tab="bpm-tab-event-mapping">`

Is there anyway using jQuery?

Comment: Why don't you just use an ID attribute?

Comment: If it was my decision I would like to use ID, now it's a big project and we have to use classes instead of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

assuming it always have class `tab-li`.  You can use

```
$('.tab-li').attr('class');
```

It will return all classes applied to it.
or as @Hassan mentioned use some `id` so it will be (assuming li_id is id here)

```
$('#li_id').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find it by attribute `bpm-tab` using this code:

```
$("li[bpm-tab = bpm-tab-event-mapping]")
```

But I recommend you add an `id` attribute to this element and search by id

```
<li class="tab-li tab-error tab-active" bpm-tab="bpm-tab-event-mapping" id="anyId">
```

Search code:

```
$("#anyId");
```

Search by id is faster.